# How to make equivalent circuit of input pin of PIC16F15375 controller for LTspice simulation

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I want to simulate the input pin of the PIC16F15375 controller in LTspice to determine the current. However, I am not aware of the specific circuit diagram.

Comment: They provide block diagrams, only. At least, publicly. I've had success, on a few occasions, of getting copies of internal documents for some pins (the two oscillator pins, the class-A amplifier inside, and some very interesting nearby details.) But you need a reason, a justification. Given a good reason, they have been helpful so far as I'm aware. And I've been unwilling to tread on their good will, without good reason. So I don't know how they would respond, if I didn't have much of a good reason. Probably would say no, though. Cobble something up in the simulator that meets your needs?

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: i need to verify the current of the input pin

Comment: Analog or digital input?